# How to check if the web connection is established?

Tags: php, web, connection

**Disambiguation:** 'connection' doesn't mean database connection.

#### REAL QUESTION

> **Scenario 1:** I am taking weather feed from a 3rd party site, and it's working fine. Suddenly my client complained that it's broken, and showing an error. Then quickly I just simply commented out the codes.
>
> **Scenario 2:** Suppose I embedded Google fonts into my website and it's looking fine. Suddenly Google's services are banned in a country, and my site looks dumb.

#### PROBABLE SOLUTION

If I can put a checker like:

```
<?php

// suppose this is the URL of my connection I need to connect my site on loading
$connection = http://www.feed-from-somewhere.com/feed/my-feed123

if ( isset( $connection ) ) {

   // show the feed from 3rd party site

} else {

   // do my backup plan for the feed instead

}
?>
```

But I can't find any way. If I can do such thing than it would be better for all such 3rd party sharing and site won't malfunction in future.

Waiting for a nice solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the fopen() function in php.
as described in the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) fopen() --

> "If filename is of the form "scheme://...", it is assumed to be a URL
>   and PHP will search for a protocol handler (also known as a wrapper)
>   for that scheme."...

example could be:

```
@$connection = fopen("http://iewuhf.com/", "r");
//note @ is used to suppress the error ortherwise, if connection fails, a warning 
//will be displayed 

if(!$connection){
 echo 'false';
}else{
 echo 'true';
}
```